# How to trigger AWS Amplify preview build for reopened GitHub pull requests?

Tags: github, aws-amplify, pull-request

I have AWS Amplify configured to create previews for Pull Requests in GitHub. Whenever a PR is created or updated the preview branch is created or upadted. However, when a PR is closed and reopened a preview branch is not created. If I close the PR and open a brand new PR then the preview is created, but all the conversation from the previous PR are lost this way.

I expected just using the GitHub Reopen Pull Request button would trigger a recreation of the preview build, but I don't see anything triggered in either GitHub or Amplify.

Has anyone found a way to trigger the recreation of the preview branch when a PR is reopened?

Answer (score 0):

After re-opening the PR you can simply push a new commit to the branch, like merging the latest changes from master.